# Custom control doesn't resize as window resizes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, responsiveness

I have a custom control with this layout:

```xml
<Border x:Name="PART_OuterBorder"
    CornerRadius="1000"
    BorderThickness="3"
    BorderBrush="Black">
    <Border.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#438F40"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.95" Color="#0D441D"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="2" Color="#106E42"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>

    <Border x:Name="PART_InnerBorder"
        CornerRadius="1000">
        <Border.Background>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#333439"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.5" Color="#000"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <userControls:DraggableElement x:Name="PART_DraggableElement"
                                Width="16" Height="16"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

As you can see I didn't set width and height for 2 borders, and I used the control in a grid row:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <customControls:myCustomControl Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

But the control doesn't resize as I resize window. Btw it fixes its size if I put it in a smaller or larger grid cell, that's the only time it fixes its size.

Also I considered using a ViewBox as parent of the borders in my custom control's template, but that changes the entire layout:

Normal:

[image]

with ViewBox:

[image]

Comment: Try putting your control in a DockPanel if you want it to resize with the Window.

Comment: @Russ Just tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according your words and codes, your picture was as expected.
Because you didn't set the width and heigth of "myCustomControl", so the two border would fill the all area of myCustomControl. And the with and height of DraggableElement were set, it was fixed size.
When you used viewbox, the viewbox would think the with and height of myCustomControl were DraggableElement's. So the yellow would take the all area.
If you want your control not  fill your area, but also keep the proportion, you can set the with and height of PART_OuterBorder and use viewbox around  PART_OuterBorder.
Code like this:

```
 <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
        <Border  Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Border x:Name="PART_OuterBorder" 
                    CornerRadius="1000"
                    BorderThickness="3"
                    BorderBrush="Black">
                <Border.Background>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#438F40"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.95" Color="#0D441D"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="2" Color="#106E42"/>
                        </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>

                <Border x:Name="PART_InnerBorder"
                         CornerRadius="1000">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <RadialGradientBrush>
                            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#333439"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.5" Color="#000"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">haha</TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, That's it. Also could keep 1:1 aspect ratio of control by setting `Stretch` of ViewBox to `Uniform` instead of `Fill`.